# How to installing perl Inline::Python in ubuntu 16.04 , python 3.6

Tags: perl, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6

I have python code which i want to use in perl application, for this I am trying to use perl inline::python module. But I am facing problem in installing this perl module.  I get the following error:

"lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream generated with LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 4.1"

I have python 3.6 (using anaconda 3) on ubuntu 16.04 system , gcc: 5.4.0. Not getting exactly how to fix this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why don't you launch your python script with

```
system "python yourScript.py";
```

into your perl script?